# Sigsegv in malloc

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, malloc

I want to save a struct containing a pointer that I use as a dynamic array but when I load the struct and malloc this pointer, it fails.

I have three structs (Orientation, ShipType, Status and PlayerType are enumerations, you can replace them by Int) :

```
struct Map
{
    int width, height;
    int* cases;
};
typedef struct Map Map;

struct Ship
{
    int x, y, length, firstShoot, color;
    int hasBeenDiscovered;
    Orientation orientation;
    ShipType type;
    Status status;
};
typedef struct Ship Ship;

struct Player
{
    int activeShips;
    Map map[2];
    char lastMoves[5][128];
    Ship ships[10];
    PlayerType type;
    int shipcolor[4];
    int color;
};
typedef struct Player Player;
```

I declare an array of 2 Player like this : `Player players[2];` and initialize their properties. Then I want to save the struct in a file in order to load it afterwards.
Also, I use the Map struct as a 2d dynamic array using four functions :

```
void mallocMap(Map* map, int width, int height)
{
    map->cases = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);

    map->width = width;
    map->height = height;

    if (map->cases == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erreur d'allocation de memoire\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

void freeMap(Map* map)
{
    free(map->cases);
}

int getMapValue(Map map, int x, int y)
{
    return *(map.cases + y*map.width + x);
}

void setMapValue(Map* map, int value, int x, int y)
{
    *(map->cases + y*map->width + x) = value;
}
```

So when I store the struct, `map.cases` is only a pointer and I need to store the values at its address separately like so :

```
int save(Player players[2])
{
    int* i;
    FILE* file = NULL;

    file = fopen("save.txt","w+");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(players, sizeof(Player), 2, file);

        fwrite(players[0].map[0].cases, sizeof(int), players[0].map[0].width * players[0].map[0].height, file);
        fwrite(players[0].map[1].cases, sizeof(int), players[0].map[1].width * players[0].map[1].height, file);
        fwrite(players[1].map[0].cases, sizeof(int), players[1].map[0].width * players[1].map[0].height, file);
        fwrite(players[1].map[1].cases, sizeof(int), players[1].map[1].width * players[1].map[1].height, file);
    }
    else
    {
        // error
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 1;
}
```

Each player has 2 maps so there are 4 maps to store at the end.
The problem is in my `load()` function :

```
int load(Player players[2])
{
    FILE* file = NULL;

    file = fopen("save.txt","r");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        int *i;

        fread(players, sizeof(Player), 2, file);    

        mallocMap(&players[0].map[0], players[0].map[0].width, players[0].map[0].height);
        mallocMap(&players[0].map[1], players[0].map[1].width, players[0].map[1].height);
        mallocMap(&players[1].map[0], players[1].map[0].width, players[1].map[0].height);
        mallocMap(&players[1].map[1], players[1].map[1].width, players[1].map[1].height);

        fread(players[0].map[0].cases, sizeof(int), players[0].map[0].width * players[0].map[0].height, file);
        fread(players[0].map[1].cases, sizeof(int), players[0].map[1].width * players[0].map[1].height, file);
        fread(players[1].map[0].cases, sizeof(int), players[1].map[0].width * players[1].map[0].height, file);
        fread(players[1].map[1].cases, sizeof(int), players[1].map[1].width * players[1].map[1].height, file);

    }
    else
    {
        // error
    } 

    fclose(file);

    return 1;
}
```

When I call `mapAlloc()`, it fails to allocate the memory and `exit(0)`; my program stops.

Comment: You can’t load saved pointers and use them.  You have to set the pointer to an appropriate value in the reading process.  This is called serialization and deserialization. Pointers in structures don’t restore easily. You have to work hard.  Even the writing is non-trivial.  You have to make sure the pointed at data is written.

Comment: But if I load the pointer, it will still have its previous address and I need a new one so when I call mapAlloc, it should allocate memory and set a new adress for the pointer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've declared your `load` function doesn't look right:

```
int load(Player* players[2])
```

This takes an array of *pointers to Player*, while your `save` routine takes an array of Player (i.e. `Player players[2]`).  You probably need to change it to:

```
int load(Player players[2])
```

You're also reading the values back in to the wrong address:

```
    for(i = players[0]->map[0].cases; i < players[0]->map[0].cases + players[0]->map[0].width * players[0]->map[0].height; i++)
        fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, file);
```

You're passing to `fread` the address of `i`.  That means you're reading in an `int` and storing it in `i`, which is a local `int *` and *not* the dynamically allocated array you want to write to.

Remove the address-of operator here and pass in `i` directly, just like you do when you use `fwrite`

```
        fread(i, sizeof(int), 1, file);
```

This will write the `int` that you read in into your array.

Also, there is no need to use loops to read / write individual ints here.  Just do a single read / write passing in the number of values to read/write.

So saving would be:

```
fwrite(players[0].map[0].cases, sizeof(int), players[0].map[0].width * players[0].map[0].height, file);
fwrite(players[0].map[1].cases, sizeof(int), players[0].map[1].width * players[0].map[1].height, file);
fwrite(players[1].map[0].cases, sizeof(int), players[1].map[0].width * players[1].map[0].height, file);
fwrite(players[1].map[1].cases, sizeof(int), players[1].map[1].width * players[1].map[1].height, file);
```

And loading would be:

```
fread(players[0].map[0].cases, sizeof(int), players[0].map[0].width * players[0].map[0].height, file);
fread(players[0].map[1].cases, sizeof(int), players[0].map[1].width * players[0].map[1].height, file);
fread(players[1].map[0].cases, sizeof(int), players[1].map[0].width * players[1].map[0].height, file);
fread(players[1].map[1].cases, sizeof(int), players[1].map[1].width * players[1].map[1].height, file);
```

When compiling your code, there shouldn't be any warnings.  If there are any, you're probably doing something wrong that you need to fix.

Comment: This doesn't solve the main problem here but it's much simpler to read and write the data so thanks, I will update my code

Comment: @Drakalex See my edit.  The way you defined `load` is probably wrong as well.

Comment: Also, I declared my functions like this because when I save the struct, I don't need the "real" players but I can just pass a copy of it so I save a local copy. But when I load the players, I declared my array of 2 players in a function and then I call my `load` function by passing the address of the array. With int `load(Player players[2])`, the array is local. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Drakalex When you pass an array to a function, you're actually passing in a pointer to the first element.  So you'll see the changes in the calling function.  It would also help if you show where `save` and `load` are called from.

Comment: So, weird things happened : I rewrote load() without the pointer and I don't have a sigsegv error anymore. But now my malloc fails because the line `if (map->cases == NULL)` is true in `mallocMap` and it exits my program. But it's strange because the first time I tried it, all 4 malloc worked and my game loaded as expected. Couldn't reproduce it though.

Comment: Also, the malloc fails randomly between the first one and the last one (fourth one) without any clear reason every time I launch my program.

Comment: @Drakalex You may be trying to allocate more memory than is available. Check the value passed to `malloc`.  Also, run your code through  [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).  If you're running afoul of memory bounds, it will tell you.

Comment: Nevermind, it works fine now with your optimizations and the fact that I don't user pointers. 
Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159247/discussion-between-drakalex-and-dbush).